# Complex large exponentiation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, exponentiation

I have the next exponentiation of complex number $$z ={(1+ i\sqrt 3)}^{2020}$$
I was using the Theorem of Moivre but I got a $$2 ^ {2020}$$
Then how can I get this exponentation without computer calculations? or how can I that power?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, I'm new, I made the changes. Thank you !

Comment: You just write $2^{2020}$ and be done with it.

Comment: @SeanRoberson but is a bigger number, maybe I must write other query

Comment: So you want to write a number with 608 digits. Wolfram will tell you all of them. But in an exercise like this you don't need it. This is just a test to see if you know how to use the de Moivre theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $1+\sqrt{3}i= 2\left(\cos \frac{\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{\pi}{3}\right)$. Note that the right answer is $2^{2020}\times \text{something}$, and this "something" is the outcome of the De Moivre's formula that you are trying to use.